# unresolved external symbol structs

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int WrappedVector::_N" (?_N@WrappedVector@@2HA)

header.h

```
struct WrappedVector
{
    static int _N;
    double *_x;
};
```

main.cpp

```
const int WrappedVector::_N = 3;
```

i don't understand whats wrong

Answer (score 1):

Just change the definition

```
 int WrappedVector::_N = 3; // Note no const
```

<sub>see [**LIVE DEMO1**](http://ideone.com/JODLLj)</sub>

or the declaration

```
 struct WrappedVector {
    static const int _N;
        // ^^^^^
    double *_x;
 };
```

<sub>see [**LIVE DEMO2**](http://ideone.com/3oAM8o)</sub>

consistently.

If you need the latter form (`static const int`) you can also initialize it directly in the declaration:

```
 struct WrappedVector {
    static const int _N = 3;
                     // ^^^
    double *_x;
 };
```

<sub>see [**LIVE DEMO3**](http://ideone.com/NnuyNP)</sub>

Comment: error C2086: 'int WrappedVector::_N' : redefinition 
error C2655: 'WrappedVector::_N' : definition or redeclaration illegal in current scope

IntelliSense: member "WrappedVector::_N" cannot be defined in the current scope

Comment: @borsch Can't reproduce, see the live demos I have linked in my answer.

Comment: @borsch You may also try the 3rd form I have added to my answer.